Bluesky social media link
Does CiviCRM offer the option to have a social media link (complete with icon) for Bluesky? If so how do i implement it so it appears in the social media block on emails?
Thanks
Mike

Could you clarify what you mean by "the social media block on emails?"

You can do it in Mosaico templates

@Coleman - I mean when you create the email in CiviMail you can add a Big Social Block to the template. When you go to edit it you can select all sort of social media icons to add to the block, but none for Bluesky.
@ Pradeep - Thanks. Can you tell me how you edit it to so I can add an icon/link for Bluesky?

Here's a blog post from Justin of Agileware: https://blog.agileware.com.au/civicrm/updated-mosaico-template-includes-new-social-blocks/
Back in 2019, he added a couple of options to that "Social Block" piece of the template.
Theoretically, you can do it yourself for your own install, though it's a pain, and probably a good idea to post it as an issue in the mosaico project and see who can fix it there.
https://github.com/veda-consulting-company/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/issues

Thanks Alan, mnuch apprecited.
